# Testing Android Orientation With iPod/iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, android-emulator, ipod

I have been developing an Android application and testing the orientation sensor using [SensorSimulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator). It's great, but I would really like to test it out on an actual device.

My problem is that I do not have an Android device. I do however have an iPod. Does an app exist that could send the iPod's orientation information to the android emulator on the PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no way except you develop an app yourself to do that!!